# perform calculations on rows using php form or mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

My English is little weak hope you will understand as I have tried to give example at the last. Please help me I am new in this field. Thanks you.

I have a form as follows

```
<form method="post">
<p>Amount:
<input type="text" name="receive" />
Registration:
<input type="text" name="reg_number" />
<input type="submit" name="submit_amount" value="Submit" /></p>
</form>
```

When I submit this form the following query will run

```
if(isset($_POST['submit_amount']) && count($_POST)!==0){

                $receive=$_POST['receive'];
                $reg_number=$_POST['reg_number'];

                $sql="INSERT INTO `installments`(month, amount, receive, fk_users_id)
SELECT now(), installment, $receive, id
  FROM users
 WHERE reg_number = '$reg_number'";
                $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
                if($result){
                    echo "<script>
                    alert('amount inserted');
                    </script>";
                    }else{
                        die(mysqli_error($con));
                        }
                }
```

when this query run it inserts values in the amount column from user's table and in the receive column from the form

Like:

```
installment_id |   month    | prv_arrear | amount | total | receive | arrear | fk_user_id
        1        2014-09-13                 2500               2500                1
```

I want to insert the values in prv_arrear, total and arrear column according to this formula

formula:

```
prv_arrear + amount = total

total - reveive = arrear
```

See the example

```
installment_id |    month    | prv_arrear | amount | total | receive | arrear | fk_user_id
1                 2014-09-12       0         2500     2500     1600     900        1
1                 2014-09-13      900        2500     3400     1600     900        1
```

**Note:** When all values inserted in the columns then the arrear column's value should be in the prv_arrear as in the above example.

Comment: you'll need to pull out the last entry, put those values into a base array, have the new values overwrite the old keys and insert the new row..

You also will run into problems if one of the fields is left blank, you should try and fix your sanitizing of the `$_POST` array

Comment: You'll also want to look into [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 do you need database code with this code?

Comment: @ssnobody I have read out prepared statements but can't understand it.

Comment: @iamde_coder I did not understand what are you asking, can you please give me an example if possible? As I stated in my question I am new in this field.

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 yes this is my full full php code.

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 ok I am waiting...

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 ok give me your phone no.

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 I got your email.

Comment: this is actually a pretty easy thing to do. you don't need a prepared statement and it can be done with a single MYSQL statement. However, I'm confused by your installment_id. Shouldn't that be an auto increment column? If you have 2 entries with the same ID, it will be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

this mysql statement should do it. Or very close.

```
INSERT INTO `installments`(month, amount, prv_arrear, total, arrear, receive, fk_users_id)
SELECT now(), installment, installments.arrear, installment+installments.arrear, installment+installments.arrear-$receive, $receive, id
  FROM users LEFT JOIN installments ON users.id=installments.fk_users_id 
 WHERE reg_number = '$reg_number'
 ORDER BY month DESC LIMIT 1"
```

Comment: basically, this includes the previous installment entry in the SELECT, so we can grab the previous arrear, and use that to populate prv_arrear, total and arrear columns of the new installment.

Answer (score 0):

**Please read the comment**

```
<form method="post">
<p>Amount:
<input type="text" name="receive" />
Registration:
<input type="text" name="reg_number" />
<input type="submit" name="submit_amount" value="Submit" /></p>
</form>
<?php 

$con=  mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', '25796596') or die(mysqli_error($con));
if(isset($_POST['submit_amount']) && count($_POST)!==0){

                $receive=$_POST['receive'];
                $reg_number=$_POST['reg_number'];

                $sel="select * from installments";
                $result=mysqli_query($con,$sel) or die(mysqli_error($con));



                while($row=  mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                {
                    $date=$row['month'];
                    $installment_id=$row['installment_id'];
                    $amount=$row['amount'];

                }
                //This will update your table

                $arrear=$amount-$receive;
                $total=$arrear+$receive;
                $update="update installments SET receive=$receive, arrear=$arrear, total=$total WHERE installment_id='$installment_id'";
                $result_number=  mysqli_query($con, $update) or die(mysqli_error($con));
               $onemore="select * from installments";
                $result=  mysqli_query($con, $onemore)or die(mysqli_error($con));

               while($row=  mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                {
                    $amount=$row['amount'];
                    $installment_id=$row['installment_id'];
                    $receive=$row['receive'];

                    $total=$row['total'];
                    $arrear=$row['arrear'];

                }

                $prv_arrear=$arrear;


                $total=$amount+$prv_arrear;
               //This will insert the value in the table.
                $insert_query="insert into `installments`(installment_id,prv_arrear,amount,total,receive,arrear)
                        VALUES
                        ('','$prv_arrear','$amount','$total','$receive','$arrear')";

                $result=  mysqli_query($con, $insert_query)or die(mysqli_error($con));




                }
```